# Segmentation fault while reading a file into a linked list

Tags: c, list, file, pointers, segmentation-fault

I'm using a function that returns a pointer to the next word in the file to create a linked list of the unique strings in the file. I haven't gotten to the part where I need to increment the count for each duplicate because I'm getting a "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" error while trying to print the strings in the list. Right now I'm guessing that it has something to do with me not properly handling the NULL at the end of the file, but I really don't know what I would do to fix that. Any help on this issue would be very much appreciated and thank you for your time.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_WORD_LEN 256    

struct list {
    int count;
    char string[MAX_WORD_LEN];
    struct list *next;
};

char* getNextWord(FILE* fd) {
    char c;
    char wordBuffer[MAX_WORD_LEN];
    int putChar = 0;

    while((c = fgetc(fd)) != EOF) {
        if(isalnum(c)) break;
    }
    if (c == EOF) return NULL;

    wordBuffer[putChar++] = tolower(c);

    while((c = fgetc(fd)) != EOF) {
        if(isspace(c) || putChar >= MAX_WORD_LEN -1) break;

        if(isalnum(c)) {
            wordBuffer[putChar++] = tolower(c);
        }
    }
    wordBuffer[putChar] = '\0';
    return strdup(wordBuffer);
} 

int main() {

    char filename[50];
    printf("Enter the file name: \n");
    scanf("%s\n", filename);
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");
    struct list *head, *tail, *curr; 
    head = NULL: 
    char *newWord;
    while((newWord = getNextWord(file)) != NULL) {

        strcpy(curr->string, newWord);
        free(newWord);
        if(head == NULL)
            head = curr; 
        else
            tail->next = curr;
        tail = curr;
        tail->next = NULL;
    }
    fclose(file);
    for(curr = head; curr != NULL; curr = curr->next) {
        printf("%s\n", curr->string);
    }

    return 0;
```

}

Comment: fgetc returns int, not char

Comment: I don't see any malloc in your "linked list", why?

Comment: no malloc because of strdup, although you might be right and I'm being silly

Comment: Hey Josh, frankly speaking this looks like a homework question. Maybe have a look at some more advanced C code to learn from. The code quality is horrendous like it is right now. Even if you work out the segfault.

Comment: Study more about linked list before just trying to do a quick fix, there are zillions of question and post about linked list.

Comment: Hey tcurdt, it is a homework question and I don't ask questions like "Here's what I need for this project how do I do it?" (Well except maybe once..) I usually ask about errors that I've been staring at and trying to fix for awhile to no avail. The problem with me looking at advanced code is that I don't understand it and that just doesn't benefit me. Do you know of a source where I can try to learn a bit more? I'm sorry that my code is "horrendous" to you but I'm still learning so cut me some slack man. There's really no reason to be rude about it.

Comment: I've looked at dozens of linked list questions and that's how I even got this far, moeCake. I was just confused about the segfault and I don't quite know how to use the debugger yet (shame on me). You were totally right about the malloc though and I got this to work with your and jerry's help. And unfortunately it was a quick fix.. I literally just put: curr = malloc(sizeof(struct list)); as the first line of the while loop in main and it runs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a close look at the following snippet:

```
struct list *head, *tail, *curr; 
head = NULL: 
char *newWord;
while((newWord = getNextWord(file)) != NULL) {

    strcpy(curr->string, newWord);
```

You are accessing a member of the object pointed to by `curr`, but what object is that? It is never initialized, it's quite likely the first access through it that you're seg-faulting. To solve it, set it to a new node each time through:

```
struct list *head, *tail, *curr; 
head = NULL;
char *newWord;
while((newWord = getNextWord(file)) != NULL) {
    curr = malloc(sizeof(struct list));
    strcpy(curr->string, newWord);
```

Comment: so do I need to throw in something like: curr = malloc(sizeof(struct list)) ? Is that the fix?

Comment: Yay! I did exactly that before you had to explicitly tell me. Thank you very much. After I got this to work I worked out the count in like 5 minutes. Have a good one

Comment: @Josh glad you were able to fix it. You really should dedicate some time soon to practice using a debugger, it's an essential skill. Learning to write test cases is also important, even if they're not automated in a test framework (though in this case the fact that there was an error was very clear).